# MVC 5 не находится метод помеченный атрибутом HttpPut

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[RoutePrefix("servers")]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{ 
     [HttpPut]
     [Route("test")]
     public ActionResult Test(string json)
     {
       return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
}
```

Comment: Разве PUT можно в MVC использовать? Я почему-то думал, что только в api.

Answer (score 1):

Метод, помеченный атрибутом `HttpPut` в `MVC 5` должен заработать в том случае, если Вы измените `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` в файле конфигурации в секции `system.webServer` добавить:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" 
         path="*." 
         verb="*" 
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

После этого атрибут должен начать срабатывать и метод будет виден. Либо обновиться до `MVC 5.1`, где `X-HTTP-Method-Override` - доступны. Возможно, что в пятой версии `HttpPut` - это недочет (фича). Ссылка на ответ en SO: [Attribute routing with http PUT method constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811998/5275890).

Есть еще одна идея относительно файла конфигурации, если заголовок PUT попросту блокируется, тогда попробовать в секцию `system.webServer` добавить:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Третье решение - это просто визуальный редактор для первого :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, спасибо, буду теперь знать. Просто мне как-то давно, уже не помню, показалось, что оно туда не подтянулось, после внесения изменений в конфиг. Видимо я тогда не туда смотрел :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, получается  его можно убрать из ответа? Ну, если это то же самое, только немного иначе, или пусть будет? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Я вам больше скажу - любые настройки в этом интерфейсе в конечном счете попадают в web.config. Ну или в конфиг более высокого уровня, если специально указать это.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, по поводу этого я догадался, но после публикации файл конфигурации перезаписывается... или он перезаписывается не весь и настройки в IIS так же в нем остаются?

Comment: Совершенно верно, после публикации все настройки перезаписываются.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а те настройки, которые я внес через визуальный интерфейс IIS останутся или пропадут?

Comment: После публикации ***все*** настройки перезаписываются.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, соответсвенно, лучше, если настройки будут в файле конфигурации в проекте, а не руками через интерфейс IIS, верно?

Comment: С другой стороны, обычно это даже удобно. Можно настроить локальный проект - и после публикации на сервер настройки там станут такие же как у вас локально. А еще настройки таким образом сохраняются в GIT или SVN.

Comment: Денис, нет разницы в студии вы редактируете web.config, в блокноте - или через интерфейс конфигурации IIS. Все три способа делают одно и то же - редактируют web.config!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну я к тому, что если это не локальная версия :-) то есть на серваке изменили, а в проект оно не попало